# How to split a function variable and use it later on?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a hash system for a website I'm making, although some of the pages I want to hash require a PHP id at the end. I don't want to have .php in the hash url so I'm trying to split it so I can insert it later on.

An example of what is on the html side.

```
<a href="#!/_radio/profile?id=3">link</a>
```

This is what I have so far. It all works except the extra variable isn't included at the end.

```
var Radio = {};

   Radio = {

_jsInit: function () {

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
        Radio._currentPage();
        Radio.loadPage(Radio._PageName, Radio._extra)
    });
    $(window).trigger("hashchange")

},

_currentPage: function () {
    this._PageName = location.hash.replace('#!/', '');
    if (this._PageName == "") window.location = "#!/_radio/home";
    this.values = this._PageName.split("?");
    this._extra = this.values[1];
},

loadPage: function (page, extra) {
    $('#content').fadeOut(200).load('_files/_v2/_pages/' + page + '.php?' + extra + '', function () {
      $('#content').fadeIn(400)
    });
},

};

$(document).ready(function () {
   Radio._jsInit();
});
```

Comment: If this whole question is just about URL manipulation to add .php somewhere, please show very clearly what you start with for a URL and what the desired end result is.

Comment: The url would be domain.com#!/_radio/profile?id=3

The end result splits the hash from the main domain, removes #!/ and then uses what's left to specify a file path. What doesn't work is the new variable I'm trying to include which splits ?id=3 and then sets id=3 as the "extra" variable.

Comment: Sorry, but it just isn't clear to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't know how to explain it, look at this image:
http://i.imgur.com/jUSfQUt.png

Comment: Just list the before and after finished string you want.  You don't need a picture, you don't need to use JS variables.  Just show the BEFORE and AFTER string.  That's all we need.  I should take you 5 seconds to type it in and probably take us a few minutes to write an answer after that.

Comment: Before: #!/_radio/profile?id=2

After: _files/_v2/_pages/profile.php?id=2

I do not wish to add .php in the before string.

Answer (score 0):

For this before and after:

```
Before: "#!/_radio/profile?id=2"
After: "_files/_v2/_pages/profile.php?id=2"
```

You can use a regex to find the parts of the string you want:

```js
function convertStr(str) {
    var matches = str.match(/(\/[^\/]+)(\?.*$)/);
    return "_files/_v2/_pages" + matches[1] + ".php" + matches[2];
}

// call the function and display the result in the snippet
var result = convertStr("#!/_radio/profile?id=2");    
document.write(result);
```

Or, any even simpler version that uses `.replace()`:

```js
function convertStr(str) {
    return str.replace(/(^.*)(\/[^\/]+)(\?.*$)/, "_files/_v2/_pages$2.php$3");
}

// call the function and display the result in the snippet
var result = convertStr("#!/_radio/profile?id=2");    
document.write(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the code jfriend00 provided, I got it working.

```
var Radio = {};
Radio = {

_jsInit: function () {

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
        Radio._currentPage();
        Radio.loadPage(Radio._PageName)
    });
    $(window).trigger("hashchange")

},

_currentPage: function () {
    this._PageName = location.hash.replace('#!/', '');
    if (this._PageName == "") window.location = "#!/_Radio/home";
},

loadPage: function (page) {
  var matches = page.split("?");
  var load = "_files/_v2/_pages/" + matches[0] + ".php?" + matches[1];

    $("#content").fadeOut(200).load(load, function () {
      $("#content").fadeIn(400)
    });

},

};

$(document).ready(function () {
Radio._jsInit();
});
```